# SQL Server Replace with multiple SUBSTRING SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, substring, ssms

I would like to change multiple substrings at once for example
'0100001000100'
The desired output.
' | ABC | | | | DFG | | | HIG | |'

```
REPLACE(SUBSTRING([column],1,1),' 1 ' ,' XYZ '),SUBSTRING([column],2,1),' 1 ' ,' zzz ')....
```

but does not work.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's extremely unclear how you mean your input to turn to your desired output.  However, hopefully this will clear up your confusion about the `REPLACE` function.

`REPLACE(targetstring, str1, str2)` will find each occurrence of `str1` in `targetstring` and replace it with `str2`.  So `REPLACE('I know John and John knows me', 'John', 'Fred')` would result in the string `'I know Fred and Fred knows me'`.

To chain `REPLACE`s together, so that the output from the first `REPLACE` is used as the target for the next replace, you need a structure like this:

```
REPLACE(
  REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
      'I know Fred and Fred knows me', 'Fred', 'Bill'
    ), 'know', 'like'
  ), 'and', 'but'
)
```

Next point: if you want to string together your replacement results on each character, you need to not chain the `REPLACE`s but instead join them with `+`:

```
REPLACE(SUBSTRING([column],1,1),'1','XYZ')
+
REPLACE(SUBSTRING([column],2,1),'1','zzz')
+ ...
```